# Non-local IP for next hop in routing

Tags: networking, routing, ip, subnet, mpls

I'm working with an MPLS network and I am slightly confused about some route entries.

Interfaces are (these are fake IPs):

eth0   10.10.10.1/24  (LAN)
eth1   10.9.9.1/24    (MPLS)
eht2   2.2.2.2/24     (Public)

There are a series of normal entries, such as:

Net:  10.1.0.0/24     Nexthop:  10.10.10.5
Net:  10.100.0.0/23   Nexthop  10.10.10.5     (these obviously go over eth0, but it is not specified)

The routes I can't figure out look like this:

Net:  10.166.0.0/24  Nexthop: 10.166.0.9  Interface: eth1
Net:  10.167.0.0/24  Nexthop: 10.167.0.9  Interface: eth1

These are weird because the next hop is not local.  I'm guessing because of the Interface specified, that it places it on the wire and then arps for the next hop, but it does feel a bit strange.  Is this correct, or am I missing something?  Can anyone explain the mechanism here.  I've been searching Google for hours, but it's hard to find the right keywords.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the netmask of the "MPLS" interface?

Comment: And by MPLS, you mean an isolated routed network provided by an MPLS-capable carrier? And is one of the 'normal entries' a default route?

Comment: We might be able to help you understand this if you listed the make/model/version of the router and it's OS.

Comment: It's currently on a SonicWall firewall, but it feels to me like the routing is just a GUI on top of IPTables.

Comment: I also updated the netmask, but I'm not sure they matter too much.